# Why an empty directory has large volume?

Tags: centos, ext4, ls, xfs

All the directories below are empty

```
[user@xxxx ~]$ ls -lah /home/1m
total 387M
drwxr-xr-x 22 foo foo 4.0K Apr 17 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 foo foo 4.0K Apr 17 22:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo 9.2M Apr 17 22:49 dir_1
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  13M Apr 17 22:49 dir_2
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  39M Apr 17 22:49 dir_3
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.2M Jan 19 01:00 dir_4
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  49M Apr 17 22:49 dir_5
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.3M Jan 19 01:00 dir_6
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  12M Apr 17 22:49 dir_7
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.0M Jan 19 01:00 dir_8
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.2M Jan 19 01:00 dir_9
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.3M Jan 19 01:00 dir_10
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.1M Jan 19 01:00 dir_11
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.9M Jan 19 01:00 dir_12
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo  31M Jan 19 01:00 dir_13
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  24M Apr 17 22:49 dir_14
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.9M Jan 19 01:00 dir_15
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.3M Jan 19 01:00 dir_16
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  97M Apr 17 22:49 dir_17
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  12M Apr 17 22:49 dir_18
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.9M Jan 19 01:00 dir_19
drwxrwxr-x  2 foo foo 9.3M Jan 19 01:00 dir_20
```

for example

```
[user@foo ~]$ time ls -lah /home/1m/dir_5/
total 49M
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo foo  49M Apr 17 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 foo foo 4.0K Apr 17 22:49 ..
```

Why the directory seems to have 49M of contents ?

----- EDIT -----

File system ext4

Is the same happening in xfs file system ?

Comment: Directories expand as new files are added, but depending on your file system they probably won't contract again when files are deleted, so the directory size reflects the maximum number of files that the directory has ever contained.

Comment: i never seen this, my directories are 4.0K (lmde2)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` does not tell you the size of the contents of a directory.

`ls` (in this case) tells you the size of the inode that represents the directory.

Most likely, this directory once contained a very large number of files, which required the inode to grow large enough to hold filesystem pointers to each of those files.  The directory inode does not shrink when files are removed from the directory.

Comment: No – inode size is fixed and never reported via stat/ls, but directories in ext2/3/4 _do not store_ the list of files in the inode. The file list (or htree) is stored in data blocks / extents just like a file would store its data. You're only correct that ext2/3/4 never shrinks a directory that has grown on demand.